# This session is locked - problem

Tags: unity, suspend, session, unity-greeter

When I try to login after resuming from a suspend, I get this message with a huge lock icon.

> This session is  locked - you will be redirected to the unlock dialog automatically in a few seconds

Sometimes, I have to go through the procedure **twice**.

Why does it happen and how to solve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's `light-locker`'s lockscreen. You can either disable `light-locker` by opening Light Locker Settings and turning it off, or uninstall it if you do not need it:

```
sudo apt-get remove light-locker light-locker-settings
```

Comment: What is the purpose of light-locker ? I am hesitant about removing any package that is integral part of the os.

Comment: `light-locker` is, as its name suggests, simply a screen locker. It was installed on my computer when I installed `xubuntu-desktop` on my Ubuntu installation.

Comment: All right. I am going to disable it. One more qquestion. What are the reasons that enables light-locker  locker ? because I  cannot remember doing anything that caused light-locker to start disturbing me.

Comment: Did you install xfce or any related packages recently?

Comment: yeah. pantheon.

Comment: Pantheon uses light-locker, and it appears to be enabled by default so it would affect Unity too

Comment: If the answer is to remove `light-locker`, then what will handle locking of the screen? Nothing?

Comment: @mightyiam From what I can gather, Unity has a built-in screen locker, so I suppose that'll be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

Workarround:

On freeze:

- switching to TTY (ctrl+alt+F2),
- logging in
- call "loginctl unlock-sessions"
- switch back (ctrl+alt+F7)

Note: If you're a bit dense, have never used the other TTY sessions or are having 'a darwin awards moment,' be sure to login with both the user name and then the password. This is the same as the first name in your "foo@foo:~$" name you probably never use or enter elsewhere. Then its your standard password like normal for privileged access (sudo/su/etc.).

Source:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=249053

Comment: didn't work in my case. but `loginctl list-sessions` is also only listing the tty2 (console) session and nothing else, while vt7 is still locked